# grpc-web js client request to grpc-java backend server fails when using nginx instead of envoy

Tags: java, nginx, grpc, grpc-java, grpc-web

I followed the readme of grpc-web [helloworld example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/tree/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld) to setup a local Javascript client that talks to Greeter grpc service using the protoc generated JS client stub via envoy proxy. I switched out the nodejs grpc server with a grpc-java server implemented from the **Greeter.proto** and its working fine.

[image]

I would like to use nginx instead of envoy for all the communications happening from grpc-web JS client to grpc-java backend server. So, I replaced the envoy with nginx to listen on the same port as envoy ([envoy config](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/blob/master/net/grpc/gateway/examples/helloworld/envoy.yaml))

I am using the following nginx configuration:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {

include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;
keepalive_timeout  65;

server {

    listen 8080;
    server_name _;
    
    location / {
        grpc_pass grpc://localhost:9090;
        grpc_read_timeout 0s;
        grpc_send_timeout 0s;
        
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000 always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message' always;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8' always;
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0 always;
            return 204;
        }
        
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message' always;
    }
  include servers/*;
}
```

Using this nginx configuration I am getting the following error:

**On browser:**
[image]

**nginx error_logs:**

```
2024/03/11 11:02:48 [error] 22103#0: *1 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "POST /helloworld.Greeter/SayHello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "grpc://[::1]:9090", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:63342/"
2024/03/11 11:02:48 [error] 22103#0: *1 upstream timed out (60: Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: _, request: "POST /helloworld.Greeter/SayRepeatHello HTTP/1.1", upstream: "grpc://127.0.0.1:9090", host: "localhost:8080", referrer: "http://localhost:63342/"
```

**grpc-java backend server logs:**

```
> Task :GreeterService.main()
Mar 11, 2024 11:02:12 AM org.example.server.GreeterService start
INFO: Server started...
Mar 11, 2024 11:02:48 AM io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler onDataRead
WARNING: Exception in onDataRead()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:516)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$900(NettyServerHandler.java:111)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:835)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:307)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:691)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onDataRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readDataFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:415)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:159)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:173)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:393)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Mar 11, 2024 11:02:48 AM io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler onDataRead
WARNING: Exception in onDataRead()
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:516)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$900(NettyServerHandler.java:111)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:835)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:307)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:691)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onDataRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readDataFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:415)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:159)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:173)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:393)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Mar 11, 2024 11:02:48 AM io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler onStreamError
WARNING: Stream Error
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: 
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:173)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.newStreamException(NettyServerHandler.java:812)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:522)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$900(NettyServerHandler.java:111)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:835)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:307)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:691)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onDataRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readDataFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:415)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:159)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:173)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:393)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:516)
    ... 32 more

Mar 11, 2024 11:02:48 AM io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler onStreamError
WARNING: Stream Error
io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception$StreamException: 
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2Exception.streamError(Http2Exception.java:173)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.newStreamException(NettyServerHandler.java:812)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:522)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.access$900(NettyServerHandler.java:111)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler$FrameListener.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:835)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$FrameReadListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:307)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder$PrefaceFrameListener.onDataRead(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:691)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger$1.onDataRead(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:48)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readDataFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:415)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.processPayloadState(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2FrameReader.readFrame(DefaultHttp2FrameReader.java:159)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2InboundFrameLogger.readFrame(Http2InboundFrameLogger.java:41)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.decodeFrame(DefaultHttp2ConnectionDecoder.java:173)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$FrameDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:393)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler$PrefaceDecoder.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:250)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.http2.Http2ConnectionHandler.decode(Http2ConnectionHandler.java:453)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:529)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:468)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:290)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.grpc.netty.NettyServerHandler.onDataRead(NettyServerHandler.java:516)
    ... 32 more
```

Can someone please help resolve this issue with nginx

Comment: See [Issue 1372: How do you using NGINX with gRPC-Web](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/1372) and [What are the risks of using gRPC-Web with NGINX?](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/1218#issuecomment-1445358210)

Comment: Did you get this to work? @DazWilkin or know if this works? because I have seen a lot of people saying it doesnt work for them

Comment: No, I've only used Envoy w/ gRPC-Web

Comment: Why? Didnt nginx work for you?

Comment: I don't use NGINX

Comment: What version of grpc-java are you using?

Comment: I am using the following in my build.gradle " def grpcVersion = '1.56.0'
def protobufVersion = '3.22.3' ". protobufVersion = protocVersion as well @EricAnderson

Comment: The grpc-java NPE was fixed in v1.58.0. I suggest upgrading to the newest version and seeing if the error message improves. (I expect it'll still be an error, but instead of hanging the request it should close with a detailed error message.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried v1.58.0 as you suggested and it resolved the NPE but I am getting this "io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: gRPC frame header malformed: reserved bits not zero"  & "WARNING: Expected header TE: trailers, but null is received. This means some intermediate proxy may not support trailers".  Btw, I was able to fix the NPE issue with the v1.56.0 version I have been using. I had to recompile the JS client stub of grpc-web using "mode=grpcweb" instead of "mode=grpcwebtext" but that doesnt work with gRPC server-streaming. @EricAnderson

Comment: Hi! According to [this thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/discussions/1322), "mode=grpcweb" seems like the proper option to be used. Although in [this thread](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/1391), the user seems to indicated that server streaming works with "grpcwebtext" as well. I do not have a nginx configuration so i cannot verify. But you can maybe question there as well.

Comment: Server streaming didnt work for me out of the box when using mode=grpcweb via nginx proxy. It looks like they reverted that commit (https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/pull/1408) 2 weeks back . Not sure what might be the reason @Sampajano